In my Blazor server side app I want to define a home page for intro, outside of the standard page layer. How can I do this?
In my Blazor server side app I have a standard classical page layout (On the top header section, on the left navigation menue and in the center the part for the razor pages that should be loaded.
But exceptionally I want that the default home page (the page that first opens when just the web address is entered) covers the whole screen. But when I define a home page as follows, the page is always opened in the center part of the main layout.
My home.razor page has following definition on the top
 @page "/"

How can I do this?

@layout SomeOtherLayoutPage

Yes that was the detail I needed, tankx :-)
